# Copy Files from one directory to another while creating a new folder for each file, named after the file

Tags: command-line, macos

This is my first time asking a question. I am newly trying to use command line more and more but this problem is beyond my skill.

I want to do a multi part file transfer.

1) I want to take multiple files `file_1.md`, `file_2.md`...etc, from `original_folder`and copy them to `target_folder_master`

2) I want to take each file, create a new folder based on the name of each file, for instance there should be a folder named `file_1` etc within `target_folder_master`

3) I want to be able to copy each file into its correspondingly named folder

4) and then rename each file in its target folder from its original name to `index.md`, for instance `file_1.md` should be renamed `index.md` with final path `~/file_1/index.md`

My hope is that this is all automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in *.md; do
  mkdir "/path/to/target_folder_master/${file%.*}"
  mv "$file" "/path/to/target_folder_master/${file%.*}/index.md"
done
```

Comment: question, how to i make it over write any folders that are there with the same name?

Comment: @TimFeeney by overwrite you mean remove it's contents to let just the index.md?